# Undefined variable OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to send order info to the success page in my OpenCart v2.0.3.1 store, to send data to Google Analytics.
But I'm getting this error message on success page:

```
Undefined variable: order_tracker in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.tpl on line 21
```

But I'm defining order_tracker on

```
atalog/controller/checkout/success.php


$order_tracker = array(
            'order_id'    => $order_id,
            'store_name'  => $order_info['store_name'],
            'total'       => $order_info['total'],
            'tax'         => $order_tax,
            'shipping'    => $order_shipping,
            'city'        => $order_info['payment_city'],
            'state'       => $order_info['payment_zone'],
            'country'     => $order_info['payment_country'],
            'currency'    => $order_info['currency_code'],
            'products'    => $order_products
        );

$this->data['order_tracker'] = $order_tracker;
```

**EDIT:**
I change the last line to this:

```
$data['order_tracker'] = $order_tracker;
```

And it worked.

But, now I'm getting another error:

```
Undefined variable: order_id in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/catalog/controller/checkout/success.php</b> on line <b>85</b>
```

This is line 85:

```
$order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($order_id);
```

And this is how I'm defining order_id

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {

            $order_id = $this->session->data['order_id'];
```

Comment: can you show that line 21 here.

Comment: Is that array built in a conditional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies within your array relation. If

```
$data['order_tracker'] = $order_tracker;
```

then

```
$order_id = $data['order_tracker']['order_id'];
```

will give you your order_id, not `data['order_id']`.

Edit:

In clear words, that means, you have to use this code:

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_tracker']['order_id'])) {

        $order_id = $this->session->data['order_tracker']['order_id'];
```

Comment: this is not what I want to do. I just want to retrieve the order_id before it is deleted from the cart.

Comment: Thats not the point. The point is, your variable is wrong, that's why you get `Undefined variable: order_id`. Don't use `$this->session->data['order_id']`, you must use `$this->session->data['order_tracker']['order_id']`

Comment: but order_id is defined before order_tracker. I define it on line 5 of the file.